# Prove $f(x)$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I had this problem in my calculus II exam today:

> Let $f$ be a function such that $f''$ is bounded, And for every $0\le
>  n$ there exists $n\le r \le n+1$ such that $f(r) = 0$.
> Prove that $f$ is bounded on $[0, \infty)$.

Unfortunately I failed to prove it in the exam, and I am still kind of lost here.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969)

Comment: @MartinR Im just asking for a hint, Not a full solution :)

Comment: Put another way, it would help if you showed what you tried (on the exam) or your thoughts since. Can you think of functions with the described property?

Comment: Consider $n-2\le r_1\le n-1$ and $n\le r_2\le n+1.$ Then $f'(s)=0$ for some $s$ between $r_1,$ $r_2$ thus between $n-2$ and $n+1.$ As $f''$ is bounded so is $ f'.$  basing on the above. Next $f$ is bounded for the same reason.

Comment: @Gregory I tried looking at the taylor polynomial of $f$, But could not go further. Next i tried to prove that $f$ is a periodic function, And also failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The simplest solution was sketched by the indomitable Ryszard Szwarc
in a comment.**  Too modest to post as an answer, but ...   For an exam question it is important to focus on the *simplest* possible method. It is far easier on the nerves and, besides, time pressure is always an issue.   For a research paper the same maxim applies, but mainly  since the referee will embarass you otherwise.

> **Baby Lemma**.   Suppose that  $g$ is  differentiable  on an interval $ [a,b] $,  that  $|g'(x)|  \leq M  $ on that interval, and that   $g(x_0)=0$   at some point of  $x_0 \in  [a,b]$.  Then   $|g(x)| \leq  M(b-a)  $  for all $x\in [a,b]$.
>
> **Trivial proof**:  Use the mean-value theorem: there is a point $\xi$ with   $$ |g(x)|= |g(x)-g(x_0)|= |g'(\xi)||x_0-x| \leq M(b-a).$$

*Proof for this problem (thanks to* @RyszardSzwarc):   In any interval   $[n,n+3]$  the function  $f$ has at least two distinct zeros and so  $f'$   has a zero (by Rolle's theorem).  Therefore, using the baby lemma on the interval  $[n,n+3]$    with $ g=f' $   and  $M = \sup_{x\in [0,\infty)} |f''(x)|$,
we have $  |f'(x)|\leq 3M$ for all $x\in [n,n+3]$.

Apply baby lemma again to $f$  on $ [n,n+1]$;
since $f$  is zero somewhere on  $[n,n+1]$
and  $|f'(x)|\leq 3M$,    we have $  |f(x)|\leq 3M$ for all $x\in [n,n+1]$.
(This is true for any $n$.)

---

---

**Postscript (How to answer exam questions sometimes).**

Exam questions (like this one) often have some artificial, contrived set of conditions.  If you can see past the silly details to the essence of the problem then your solution is more elegant, usually easier, and more impressive.

This is also standard advice on problem solving.  Sometimes trying for a generalization makes things clear and easier.

So here is another way to answer this, if it occurs to you during exam pressure.

"The examination problem follows immediately from the following:

**Claim.**  Suppose that   $f:[0,\infty)  \to \mathbb R$   is twice differentiable and that there is an increasing sequence of points   $\{x_n\}$   with $x_n\to \infty$   and    $f(x_n) =0$   for all  $n$.  Suppose that   $M = \sup_{x\in [0,\infty)} |f''(x)|<\infty$ and  $C =  \sup_{n} (x_{n+1}-x_n)^2 <\infty$.  Then  $|f(x)|\leq CM$ for all $x\in [x_1,\infty)$.

*Proof.*   Fix $n$.  Since $f(x_n)=f(x_{n+1})=0$ there is, by Rolle's theorem, a point in the interval $[x_n,x_{n+1}]$  where $f'$ vanishes.   By the mean-value theorem then $|f'(x)|\leq M(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ for all $x\in   [x_n,x_{n+1}].$

Since $f$ vanishes on this interval, apply the mean-value theorem again  to obtain
$$|f(x)|\leq [M(x_{n+1}-x_n)](x_{n+1}-x_n) \leq MC$$ for all $x\in [x_n,x_{n+1}].$

The inequality $|f(x)|\leq CM$  holds on every such interval and hence is valid on  $[x_1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a sequence $r_n>0$ such that $|f(r_n)|\to\infty$.

**First case: there are only finitely many $n$ for which $r_n\in[0,1]$.**

For all values of $n$ such that $r_n$ is not in $[0,1]$,

choose $s_n\in(r_n-2,r_n)$ and $t_n\in(r_n,r_n+2)$ such that $f(s_n)=f(t_n)=0$.

By MVT, there exist $u_n\in(s_n,r_n)$ and $v_n\in(r_n,t_n)$ such that $f'(u_n)=\dfrac{f(r_n)-f(s_n)}{r_n-s_n}=\dfrac{f(r_n)}{r_n-s_n}$ and $f'(v_n)=\dfrac{f(t_n)-f(r_n)}{t_n-r_n}=\dfrac{-f(r_n)}{t_n-r_n}$

By MVT again, there exists $w_n\in(u_n,v_n)$ such that $f''(w_n)=\dfrac{f'(u_n)-f'(v_n)}{u_n-v_n}=f(r_n)\times\left(\dfrac{1}{r_n-s_n}+\dfrac{1}{t_n-r_n}\right)\times\dfrac{1}{u_n-v_n}$.

Recall that $r_n-s_n$ is strictly between $0$ and $4$. So are $t_n-r_n$ and $v_n-u_n$.

Therefore $|f''(w_n)|\geq(\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{4})\times\dfrac{1}{4}\times|f(r_n)|$.

**Second case: there are infinitely many $n$ for which $r_n\in[0,1]$.**

Actually this case cannot happen, because a continuous function is bounded on a compact interval.

Comment: thanks! after some emails with the tutorial instructor he told me I can also prove this using taylor polynomial of $f$. Your approach seems more intuitive

Comment: Nice solution! I think you should have $\cdots\times\frac{1}{u_n-v_n}$ rather than $\frac{1}{v_n-u_n}$ in the penultimate equation (and $s_n\in(r_n-1,r_n)$, right? Or use $[0,2]$) and I'll say for @idoeido that since $f$ is continuous, it is bounded on $[0,1]$ so it is not possible for $|f(r_n)|\to\infty$ along the subsequence which is in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @FShrike ah yes, thanks.

Comment: by the way @FShrike cool name. Acquired from birdwatching?

Comment: Thanks :) Shrike is a bird but no; it is from an excellent book series by Philip Reeve, called the "Mortal Engines" quartet - they're targeted for younger teenagers but are quite readable even by adults, very beautiful books. Anyway, there is a great character called "Shrike". By the way, the film is **garbage** and completely tarnishes the nature of the books (as all films-of-books do, excepting maybe the Lord of the Rings films) so don't be put off by that if you've seen the film!

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution by  @Chris Sanders, because on the way a useful fact was proven. Namely,  let $f(r_1)=f(r_2)=0$ and $r_1<x<r_2.$ Then there exist $0<\lambda<1$ and $r_1<\xi<r_2$ such that
$$ f(x)=\lambda(x-r_1)(x-r_2)f''(\xi)\qquad \qquad (*)$$
Indeed
$${r_2-r_1\over (x-r_1)(x-r_2)}f(x)={f(x)\over x-r_2}-{f(x)\over x-r_1}=f'(t_2)-f'(t_1)=(t_2-t_1)f''(\xi)$$ where $r_1<t_1<\xi<t_2<r_2.$
Therefore $0<\lambda={t_2-t_1\over r_2-r_1}<1.$ The formula $(*)$ implies
$$|f(x)|\le \mathbf{{1\over 4}}(r_2-r_1)^2M,\qquad M=\displaystyle\sup_{r_1\le t\le r_2}|f''(t)|$$

Comment: Nice addition.  Still on the theme of repeated applications of the mean-value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Commentary Only.**

*[There is more that might be said by the more pedantic among us.  Do not read until you have read the other answers.]*

> *Dear StackExchange:  I am a calculus student and I have this exam question about differentiable [or twice differentiable] functions.
> The question is ...*

Let me stop you there.  There is a universal answer, valid only for calculus students, but it always works: **Use the mean-value theorem!**  Use it twice for twice differentiable functions.  Use it as many times as you need.  Don't  start with anything else.

How do I know. Well, imagine you were enrolled in a course where the *only* tool they offered the student was a *hammer*.  It is a safe prediction that you are going to see a lot of *nails*.

This old rusty tool (the mean-value theorem) dates back to the 17th century.  It is the workhorse of any calculus class, but it is extremely limited for anything modern.  By that I mean for most 19th century mathematics, let alone 20th century mathematics, or today.

So for the problem at hand:  we are assuming the function is twice differentiable and we are to use properties of $f''$ to obtain a boundedness property.  Unless you are living in the 18th century this is way too much information.  Really?  We need to assume that $f'$ exists everywhere and that $f''$ exists everywhere?  Just to show a function is bounded.

*Some History:*  Cantor faced a similar situation with second derivatives.  He was working on the uniqueness problem for trigonometric series.  So he integrated the series twice and obtained a continuous  function $R(x)$ that he needed to prove was linear.  Bright idea: if $R''(x)=0$ then $R$ is linear.  But all he had was that a weaker second derivative was zero.  He had that the **second symmetric derivative**
$$ SD_2 R(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{R(x+h)+R(x-h)- 2R(x)}{h^2}$$
would have to be zero.  Certainly $ SD_2 R(x)=R''(x)$ if the latter exists.

He was stumped.  No mean-value theorem works here: it applies to everywhere differentiable functions.  This function need not be differentiable, let alone twice differentiable. This is the 1870s and the mean-value theorem won't solve such problems.  Then he received a letter from Schwartz with the solution.

So let me place the reader in the same situation as Cantor. Will it stump you too?  Can you solve the following problem which is a generalization of the same theme of the current problem. (Try to forget the mean-value theorem, something you will need to do eventually anyway).

> *Problem*. Suppose that $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and has a second symmetric derivative at every point in $(a,b)$, that $f(a)=f(b)=0$, and
> that $\sup_{x\in (a,b)}|SD_2f(x)| =M < \infty$.   Show that
> $|f(x)|\leq M(b-a)^2$.